# C Language: BASIC has ? myVar to show name & value. Available in C?

Tags: c, variables, printing, basic

C Language:

BASIC has 
    print **? myVar**
that bundles up the variable name & value. 
Available in C? I'm using a flavor of C for microcontrollers
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a macro:

```
#define PR_INT(x) printf(#x"=%d\n",x)
#define PR_CHAR(x) printf(#x"=%c\n",x)
#define PR_STRING(x) printf(#x"=%s\n",x)
```

and so on

There is no such feature built into the language because the variable name is just a label,which the compiler may not need after the parsing stage (still needs the global variables)

Comment: Got it. Macro solution is new to me, I'll try now. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: bashrc: to accept I just click check to green, right? No second step to confirm or lock in?